# Importing module in an app service on Azure does not work

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have a web job in Azure (powershell script hosted on Azure Appservice and runs on a timely manner). It is working fine otherwise but I cannot load Azure module from offline source in it. On my local machine I can load

```
Import-Module C:\Modules\Azure\Az
```

but on AppService I have uploaded the same module and try loading it like this and it does not load saying there is not module file here.

```
Import-Module D:\home\site\sharedmodules\Azure\Az
```

P.S: I have downloaded module with the following command on local disk as well and it works

```
Save-Module -Name Az -Path '.\PowerShell\modules' -Force
```

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't have the required access to the production environment to test this out. And we had to change the way we are doing it (to avoid loading Az module at all)

Comment: You mean you could not access the kudu site?

Comment: no, couldn't play with environment for installing python, adding handlers etc. 
I tried installing Az module from kudus though and it required admin permissions on the server (which ofcourse is not available to me)

Comment: You used the web.config or the handler mapping, could you provide more information? And yes if you install az directly it will require admin, so have to use the pip to install.

Answer (score 0):

I can also reproduce your issue, not sure why, it works fine on local.

Here is just a workaround, if you want to run a powershell script, you could use the [Azure Powershell Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks) in the automation account, it supports you to schedule the runbook at a specific time, see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules). You could also import the modules you want to use e.g. `Az` to the automation account.

For more details about the powershell runbook, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

If load the module directly it won't work, you could install azure-cli with [pip](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/) refer to my below steps.

1. Add python extension to azure. Details you could refer to this doc:[How to set up a Python environment on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service). I add the python extension, then in the `Configuration` add a handler mapping.

[image]

2. Install azure-cli with pip. After first step you will be able to use pip, then just run `pip install azure-cli` in the kudu CMD.
3. Set the environment variable `PATH`, the azure-cli will be installed in the `D:\home\python364x86\Scripts` folder, add a `applicationHost.xdt` under `D:\home\site` with below content.

   ```
       <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\python364x86\Scripts" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
     </environmentVariables>
   </runtime>
   ```
4. Test azure-cli, if success then upload you powershell webjob. In my test webjob, I just use below command:

   ```
   $version=az --version

   $version
   ```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue in the import module line.

Comment: From Review: Could you please show us the whole command required for fixing the issue?